# Unable to get the right value of a certain amount from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python using selenium to get the converted value of a certain amount. The amount produces converted value when the earlier is made to put in a placeholder. The newly produced value is found adjacent to the amount. When I put any amount manually in that placeholder, I get a converted value accordingly but when I do the same programmatically, the value remains unchanged and as a result my scraper gets `0` as value. How can I make it work?

Link to that webpage: [weblink](https://www.gdax.com/trade/LTC-EUR)

The script I've tried with:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from contextlib import closing
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

with closing(Chrome()) as driver:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    driver.get("find_the_link_above")
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".OrderForm_input-box_XkGmi input[name='amount']"))).send_keys(100)
    item = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"OrderForm_total_6EL8d"))).text
    print(item)
```

When I put any amount to the placeholder manually, the change can be seen like below:

[image]

But, when I do the same using the script, this is how it looks like:

[image]

I've marked the valuees with black color to let you know what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you are sending the value too early so that value is not reflecting after entering the amount value. Here i am waiting for `EUR SPREAD` element to load before setting the amount value.You can use the same element or any other of your chose but make sure page loads completely with that object and then send the amount value.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
chrome_path = r"path"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://www.gdax.com/trade/LTC-EUR")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='OrderBookPanel_text_33dbp']")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='amount']"))).send_keys(100)
item = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"OrderForm_total_6EL8d"))).text
print(item)
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Could you tell me why you choose this class  `OrderBookPanel_text_33dbp` to check for the availability? Because, if i choose another one as in, what i did earlier it can't get the value. There is something special with this class. A oneliner explanation would be very helpful.

Comment: What i observed is, LTC value was not reflecting if we enter amount value before page completely loads. So `OrderBookPanel_text_33dbp` was the element loading at the end and so i have used.

Comment: If you don't want to use `OrderBookPanel_text_33dbp` , you can wait until first grid loading thing disappear. Any kind of validation would be fine until that validation make sure the complete page loading.

Comment: Thanks Pradeep hebbar, for the clarity.